# How do interpret python3's help output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, introspection

In python3, the help output for sorted, for example, is:

"sorted(iterable, /, *, key=None, reverse=False)"

What does the '/' and '*' mean?

help(sorted)

python2 output is

sorted(iterable, cmp=None, key=None, reverse=False) --> new sorted list

so what is the '/' and '*' in python3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/` marks the end of positional-only parameters and the beginning of positional-or-keyword parameters, while `*` marks the end of positional-or-keyword parameters and the beginning of keyword-only parameters.

In case of the `sorted` function where the signature is `sorted(iterable, /, *, key=None, reverse=False)`, it means that the `iterable` parameter can only be specified as a positional argument so you can't call `sorted(iterable=some_list)`, and that the `key` and `reverse` parameters can only be specified as keyword arguments, so you can't call `sorted(some_list, some_func, True)`.

Please refer to [PEP-0457](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0457/) for more details.